# Upstart Zookeeper script hangs and does not start

Tags: ubuntu, services, upstart

I've been writing a Zookeeper upstart service script as follows:

```
description "ZooKeeper"

limit nofile 32768 32768

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on [!12345]

respawn
respawn limit 2 5

umask 007

kill timeout 300

script
exec sudo {{dir}}/bin/zkServer.sh start {{dir}}/conf/zoo.cfg
end script
```

however, the problem is that:

1. The service start hangs
2. Zookeeper's PID cannot be seen by e.g. ps aux
3. Zookeeper cannot be restarted

Hence, my question is - what exactly could be wrong in the script above?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
script
exec sudo {{dir}}/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground {{dir}}/conf/zoo.cfg 
end script
```